# How do I set the new resolution of an image

Tags: applescript

I am a segment of my script where I scale down an image from 1200 dpi to 300 dpi.

I am trying to do this:

```
repeat with i in input
    tell application "Image Events"
        launch
        set my_image to open i
        set resolution to {300,300}
        set color space to CMYK
        save my_image as TIFF
```

but resolution is read only????

How can I set the new resolution of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to call `sips` to set it for you:

```
do shell script "sips -s dpiHeight 300 -s dpiWidth 300 " & my_image
```

Comment: how do I do that from inside that loop on applescript?

Comment: my_image is the handler that points to the image inside the applescript. How do I pass that to sips using this command of yours?